# where can I get python references for kinect. (poor documentacion)

Tags: python, pygame, kinect

Where can i get python references for kinect. I would like to pull out the X,Y,Z with data from the kinect.
I have:
The kinect
The kinect SDK
Python 2.7 3.2 and 3.3
all with
Numpy and PyGame
I would like to set my kinect angle as well .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there's openkinect with a python wrapper http://openkinect.org/wiki/Python_Wrapper never tried this one, but openkinect is pretty cool itself by itself

also, you may want to check this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BoMQqW0lxVE

as always, google is your best friend here